# Delphi case statement for integer ranges

Tags: delphi

I have a function which is being passed an integer value, representing a step value.
There are 5 seperate conditions I want to test for:
Value =0
Value =1 
Value =-1
Value >1
Value <-1

Currently this is implemented as a set of if statements, and I would like to change this for a case statement. I have no problems with the specific value cases, or even a limited range (say 1..10)  but how do i write a case representing Value >1  , or Value <-1?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var
  MyValue: integer;

...

case MyValue of
  Low(Integer)..-2:
    beep;
  -1:
    beep;
  0:
    beep;
  +1:
    beep;
  2..High(Integer):
    beep;
end;
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! I knew there must be some way to do it, but it's not very obvious. Thanks.

Comment: Great didn't new that case supports intervals greater than 255 i confused them with set of

Comment: +1 might have to refactor this to `low(NativeInt)` and `high(NativeInt)` in XE2  ;-)

Comment: @David Heffernan, thats not correct fact, read up on generic vs. fundamental types.

Comment: @David Heffernan, yes, when generic types can vary per platform, one should use fundamental types

Comment: @David Heffernan, `Integer` size varies even within Borland implementations which always been nailed to x86 platform.

Comment: BTW, `Tag` name isnt much informative here, @Andreas Rejbrand. Original documentation uses `selector-expression` (which by definition is of `ordinal` type).

Comment: @Downvoter - yes, Integer is 16-bit in Delphi 1.0 and 32-bit in all other Delphi versions

What other implementation variations are you thinking of, and just how likely is it do we think that this question and any answers to it, will be compiled using Delphi 1.0 ?

Just curious.

Comment: @Deltics, your sentence perfectly illustrates unportability of borland implementations. [Pascal has been subsetted, modified and worse.](http://www.standardpascal.org/) OP asks about Pascal construct, not Delphi specific one, so lets not use vendor lock-in here.

Comment: @Downvoter... The OP makes NO mention of "Pascal" anywhere but specifically mentions "Delphi" in the question and has tagged the question as "delphi".  You might want to step OUT of the light for a minute... it appears to be getting in your eyes.  ;)