# Case statement against constant set of integers?

Tags: delphi, set, enumeration

### Short Version

Given:

```
    const
       Whitespace = [$0009, $000A, $000C, $0020];
```

- Works: `if ch in Whitespace then...`
- Fails: `case ch of Whitespace: ...`

### Long Version

Normally, if you were to have a `case` statement, you can include various values for each case, eg:

```pascal
var
  ch: UCS4Char; // unsigned 32-bit

case ch of
48..57: {asciiDigit}; //i.e. '0'..'9'
65..70: {asciiUpperHexDigit}; //i.e. 'A'..'F'
97..102: {asciiLowerHexDigit}; //i.e. 'a'..'f'
end;
```

That works, but I would like these values to be constants:

```pascal
const
  //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#code-points
  asciiDigit         = [Ord('0')..Ord('9')]; //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-digit
  asciiUpperHexDigit = [Ord('A')..Ord('F')]; //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-upper-hex-digit
  asciiLowerHexDigit = [Ord('a')..Ord('f')]; //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-lower-hex-digit
  asciiHexDigit      = asciiUpperHexDigit + asciiLowerHexDigit; //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-hex-digit
  asciiUpperAlpha    = [Ord('A')..Ord('Z')]; //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-upper-alpha
  asciiLowerAlpha    = [Ord('a')..Ord('z')]; //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-lower-alpha
  asciiAlpha         = asciiUpperAlpha + asciiLowerAlpha; //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-alpha
  asciiAlphaNumeric  = asciiDigit + asciiAlpha; //https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-alphanumeric
```

Is there **any** arrangement of **any** syntax that will allow:

- `case`ing a `Cardinal`
- against a *"set of `Cardinal`s"*?

Or am I permanently stuck with the following?

```pascal
var
  ch: UCS4Char; //unsigned 32-bit

case ch of
Ord('!'): FState := MarkupDeclarationOpenState;
Ord('/'): FState := EndTagOpenState;
Ord('?'): AddParseError('unexpected-question-mark-instead-of-tag-name');
UEOF: AddParseError('eof-before-tag-name parse error');
Whitespace: FState := SharkTankContosoGrobber;
else
  if ch in asciiDigit then
  begin
    FReconsume := True;
    FState := tsTagNameState;
  end
  else
    AddParseError('invalid-first-character-of-tag-name parse error');
end;
```

Obviously, using the conceptual `case` matches the logic being performed; having to do `if-elseif` is...lesser.

**Note**: I don't need it to *actually* be a Delphi *"`set`"*, that is a specific term with a specific meaning. I just want:

```
case ch of Whitespace: ...
```

to work the same way:

```
if ch in Whitespace then...
```

already does work.

And we know the compiler already is OK with comparing a Cardinal to a "set",  because the following already works:

```
case ch of
$000A, $000D, $0009, $0032: ...
end;
```

It's comparing a Cardinal to a "set of numbers".

## Bonus Reading

- [Delphi case statement for integer ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628446/delphi-case-statement-for-integer-ranges)
- [Efficiently compare an integer against a static list of integers in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212592/efficiently-compare-an-integer-against-a-static-list-of-integers-in-delphi)
- [any way to compare an integer variable to a list of integers in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684681/any-way-to-compare-an-integer-variable-to-a-list-of-integers-in-if-statement)
- [What Delphi type for 'set of integer'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790770/what-delphi-type-for-set-of-integer)

Comment: The base type of a set cannot be bigger than a byte, so there is no such thing as `set of Cardinal`. Such a variable would be 512 MB.

Comment: Try to add #$2009, #$2003 etc. to your `Whitespace` constant (in your first code block).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not supported.

According to the official [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Case_Statements):

> A case statement has the form:
>
> ```
> case selectorExpression of
>   caseList1: statement1;
>    ...
>   caseListn: statementn;
> end
> ```
>
> where [...] each `caseList` is one of the following:
>
> - A numeral, declared constant, or other expression that the compiler can evaluate without executing your program. It must be of an ordinal type compatible with `selectorExpression`. [...]
> - A subrange having the form `First..Last`, where `First` and `Last` both satisfy the criterion above and `First` is less than or equal to `Last`.
> - A list having the form `item1, ..., itemn`, where each item satisfies one of the criteria above.

Hence, this only allows single values, explicit ranges, and lists of such values, as part of the `case` syntax.

Although the Delphi documentation is good, it isn't perfect and you cannot rely on it to 100%. However, I'm sure all experienced Delphi developers will agree that a `caseList` cannot be a predeclared single-identifier "collection" of ordinal values compatible with `selectorExpression`.

You may file a feature request at [Embarcadero's Jira](https://quality.embarcadero.com/).

---

But you can use the range syntax and a previously declared *subrange type* (not *set constant*) to achieve something partly similar:

```pascal
type
  TAsciiDigit = '0'..'9';
  TAsciiLatinCapitalLetter = 'A'..'Z';
  TAsciiLatinSmallLetter = 'a'..'z';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  var c := 'R';

  case c of
    Low(TAsciiDigit) .. High(TAsciiDigit):
      ShowMessage('Digit!');
    Low(TAsciiLatinCapitalLetter) .. High(TAsciiLatinCapitalLetter):
      ShowMessage('Capital!');
    Low(TAsciiLatinSmallLetter) .. High(TAsciiLatinSmallLetter):
      ShowMessage('Small letter!');
  else
    ShowMessage('Something else.');
  end;

end;
```

---

*Bonus remark:* In fact, the non-100% accuracy of the documentation can be seen in the section quoted above:

> `selectorExpression` is any expression of an ordinal type smaller than 32 bits

That's nonsense. `selectorExpression` certainly can be a 32-bit integer.